# Calling an inner class in a main method in java

Tags: java, arraylist, static, program-entry-point

So I've already tried looking up what's causing this and comparing my code for any possible errors to others and I have yet to find anything else that would lead to this issue.

I'm trying to call the inner class Pair in order to store data.

**Quick info about my project.**

Take voting data and determine someone's political stance on it.
Right now I'm just trying to parse the data.
*Example data*

```
Rep1[tab]D[tab]-+-+-++---
```

I'm storing it as...

```
ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>
```

So rep1 is the place in the ArrayList and then D and -+-+-++--- are the pair.

But I'm having an issue with trying to instantiate the Pair class " non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

specifically

```
C:\Users\Stephanie\Desktop>javac DecisionTree.java
DecisionTree.java:26: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
                        Pair pair = new Pair();
                                    ^
1 error
```

Code:

```
public class DecisionTree{  
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Pair> data = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    FileReader input = new FileReader ("voting-data.tsv");
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(input);
    String line = null;

    while((line=buff.readLine())!=null)
    {
        Pair pair = new Pair();
        String[] array = line.split("\\t");
        pair.setLabel(array[1]);
        pair.setRecord(array[2]);
        data.add(pair);
    }
}


/**
* Private class to handle my inner data
*/
public class Pair
{
    private String label;
    private String record;
    /**
    * contructor
    *@param String label, the label of the person's party
    *@param String record, their voting record
    */
    private Pair(String label, String record)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.record = record;
    }
    /**
    * empty contructor
    */
    private Pair()
    {

    }
    /**
    * get the label
    *@return String label, the label of the person's party
    */
    private String getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }       
    /**
    * get the record
    *@return String record, their voting record
    */
    private String getRecord()
    {
        return record;
    }       
    /**
    * set the label
    *@param String label, the label of the person's party
    */
    private void setLabel(String label)
    {
        this.label=label;
    }       
    /**
    * set the record
    *@param String record, their voting record
    */
    private void setRecord(String record)
    {
        this.record=record;
    }   
}
```

}

Thanks! I feel like I'm missing something really basic, it's just been a long time since I've used Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inner class and static nested class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-static inner classes are associated with an instance of the enclosing class in Java. This means that an instance of class `Pair` in your example belongs to a specific instance of `DecisionTree`. You can only create it in the context of an instance of `DecisionTree`. You can't directly create a `Pair` using `new Pair()` in the `main()` method, because that method is static (so, it's not associated with an instance of `DecisionTree`).

If you don't want this, make the inner class `static`:

```
public class DecisionTree {
    // ...

    public static class Pair {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Pair` `static`, i.e.:

```
public static class Pair
```

Otherwise you cannot construct a `Pair` object in `main()`, because it is a static method.  Inner classes (as opposed to static nested classes) require a surrounding instance.

Also your comment says `Pair` is private, but the class is marked `public`.  Make it `private` if that is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Pair is an inner class. Instances of an inner class are associated with instances of the class they are a member of, and can only be created in the context of a parent instance. 
If you declare Pair static it will become a nested class, which is more like a regular class. The enclosing class only contributes its name.